# Find all keys in an array of hash with empty value

Tags: ruby

How can I find all keys in an array of hash with empty or specific value?

`hash.key(value`) return only 1 key... I can splise the hash or loop the hash using each/map methods, but i don't like that solution.

Comment: You can use `hash.select` here

Comment: Thank you! That helped. After select i call keys method )

Answer (score 5):

Example :

```
> hash = {:a => 1, :b =>nil, :c =>4, :d => "", :e => 5}
> selected_values = [1,4,5]
```

### Select Keys for Empty Values:

```
> hash.select{|_,v| v.nil? || v == ""}.keys
#=> [:b, :d]
```

### Select Keys for Specific values:

**Solution 1:**

```
> hash.select{|k,v| selected_values.include?(v)}.keys
#=> [:a, :c, :e]
```

**Solution 2:**

```
> matcher = ->(key,value) { selected_values.include?(value) }
> hash.select(&matcher).keys
#=> [:a, :c, :e]
```

Comment: Instead of using `v.nil? || v == ""` you could also type `v.blank?`

Comment: @joost : It supports in Rails, not in plain ruby, and in question `rails` is not tagged

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to obtain the keys corresponding to several values, you might consider constructing a hash that will provide that information. Suppose, for example,

```
g = { :dog=>"gone", :cat=>"", :pig=>nil, :owl=>"", :bat=>nil, :ant=>"gone" }
```

then construct

```
h = g.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| (h[v] ||= []) << k }
  #=> {"gone"=>[:dog, :ant], ""=>[:cat, :owl], nil=>[:pig, :bat]}
```

So now, to obtain the keys having a specific value, say `"gone"`, we simply retrieve the value of `"gone"`:

```
h["gone"]
  #=> [:dog, :ant]
```

If `empty` means a value that is `nil` or an empty string, we obtain `h`'s keys that have empty values by combining the values for `nil` and `""`:

```
h[nil].concat h['']
  #=> [:pig, :bat, :cat, :owl]
```

Regarding `(h[v] ||= []) << k`, if h (which initially is empty) does not yet have a key `v`, `h[v] #=> nil`, so

```
(h[v] ||= []) << k
  #=> (h[v] = h[v] || []) << k
  #   (h[v] = nil || []) << k
  #   (h[v] = []) << k
  #   h[v] = [k]
```

Alternatively, one can write

```
h = g.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(k,v),h| h[v] << k }
```

Whenever the (initially empty) hash represented by the block variable `h` does not have a key `k`, the block `{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }` is executed prior to `h[k] << k`.